# Why do system stored procs fail with the owner included?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, the following works:

```
sp_help MyProc
sp_depends MyTable
```

But if you include the owner, it fails with a syntax error:

```
sp_help dbo.MyProc
sp_depends dbo.MyTable
```

It makes you put the param in quotes for it to work.  Yet, I could do the following no problem:

```
exec dbo.MyProc
```

Why the inconsistency?  Is there a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQL Server` allows you to omit single quotes for single-word string parameters:

This will output `test`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_test (@objname NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT  @objname
END

prc_test test
```

, however this will fail:

```
prc_Test Cannot_insert_a_dot.here
```

Here, `test` is a short form of `'test'` (note the single quotes).

`SP_HELP` is a stored procedure that expects a `VARCHAR` parameter, while `EXECUTE` expects an object identifier (of which a database name is a valid part)

```
exec dbo.MyProc
```

Always enclose your string constants into single quotes, and it can be a good idea to enclose the object names into brackets:

```
EXEC [dbo].[myproc]
```

Comment: I should have known that you were going to complete your answer

Answer (score 1):

Completing the **Quassnoi** answer.

`SP_Help` is a SP in the master DB that takes a `NVarchar` argument for the name of the SP.
If you use it consistently, you should call

```
sp_help 'MyProc'
```

And, with this same convention

```
sp_help 'dbo.MyProc'
```

works fine.

The thing is that, when you call `sp_help MyProc` SQL Server adds the single quotes for you, but this does not work when using a dot in the name of the SP.